# Case When SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I am still new to LINQ and trying to convert this SQL command

```
Id     | TitleName
------ | ------
1      | Accounts
2      | Buyer
3      | Engineer
4      | Other
5      | Apple  


SELECT Id, TitleName

    FROM dbo.Title

       ORDER BY 

         CASE WHEN TitleName = 'Other'

            THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC, TitleName ASC
```

This selects the table and ascends it in alphabetical order

Then it grabs 'Other' and forces it to the bottom.

So it ends up like this

```
Id     | TitleName
------ | ------
1      | Accounts
5      | Apple  
2      | Buyer
3      | Engineer
4      | Other
```

This works in SQL,
What is the best approach to achieve this using LINQ ?

Edit: Issue Resolved

```
  var queryAllCustomerTitle = from cust in _titleRepository.Table
                              orderby cust.TitleName == "Other" ? 1 : 0, cust.TitleName
                              select cust;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the ternary operator

`OrderByDescending(a=>a.TitleName == "Other" ? 0:1).ThenBy(a=>a.TitleName)`